Leaflet sidebar plugin and markers
I have the following HTML/PHP page, where I use Leaflet JS and the plugin Leaflet Sidebar. Two markers should be shown on the map and when they are clicked upon a sidebar should open with some information (retrieved via PHP in my case).
I must have something wrong because the map shows up without the two markers.
I can't spot the problem. Can you please give some hints?
<html>
 <head>
  <title>map</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.95/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-sA+zWATbFveLLNqWO2gtiw3HL/lh1giY/Inf1BJ0z14=" crossorigin=""/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/L.Control.Sidebar.css" />

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.95/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

A FEW PHP VARIABLES TO BE ECHOED IN THE SIDEBAR...

$lat1 = $objResult["lat1"];
$lon1 = $objResult["lon1"];
$cap1 = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($objResult["cap1"]));
$testo1=nl2br(addslashes($objResult["testo1"]));

$lat2 = $objResult["lat2"];
$lon2 = $objResult["lon2"];
$cap2 = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($objResult["cap2"]));
$testo2=nl2br(addslashes($objResult["testo2"]));
?>
<center>
 <div id="map" class="embed-container"></div>
</center>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-o9N1jGDZrf5tS+Ft4gbIK7mYMipq9lqpVJ91xHSyKhg=" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/0.2.6/oms.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([34.169090845221135, 27.773437499999996], 3);
L.control.scale({imperial: false}).addTo(map);

var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);

var pol = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 9
  }).addTo(map);

var sat = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
  {
    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community',
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 9
  });

var baseMaps = {
    "politica": pol,
    "satellitare": sat
};
L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
</script>

<script>
  var map = L.map('map').setView([34.169090845221135, 27.773437499999996], 3);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      maxZoom: 8,
      minZoom: 3
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
<script>
        var sidebar_1 = L.control.sidebar('sidebar_1', {
            closeButton: true,
            position: 'left'
        });

        sidebar_1.setContent('<b>Capitolo 1</b>: <?=$cap1;?><br><br><?=$testo1;?><br>');

        map.addControl(sidebar_1);
        setTimeout(function () {
            sidebar_1.hide();
        }, 500);

        var marker1 = L.marker([<?php echo $lat1;?>, <?php echo $lon1;?>]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
            sidebar_1.toggle();
        });
</script>
<script>
        var sidebar_2 = L.control.sidebar('sidebar_2', {
            closeButton: true,
            position: 'left'
        });

        sidebar_2.setContent('<b>Capitolo 2</b>: <?=$cap2;?><br><br><?=$testo2;?><br>');

        map.addControl(sidebar_2);
        setTimeout(function () {
            sidebar_2.hide();
        }, 500);

        var marker2 = L.marker([<?php echo $lat2;?>, <?php echo $lon2;?>]).addTo(map).on('click', function () {
            sidebar_2.toggle();
        });
</script>
<script>
 oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
  for (var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; i ++) markers[i].setIcon(new lightIcon());
  map.closePopup();
 });
 oms.addListener('unspiderfy', function(markers) {
  for (var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; i ++) markers[i].setIcon(new darkIcon());
 });
</script>
<script>
var latlngs = Array();

//Get latlng from each marker
latlngs.push(marker1.getLatLng());
latlngs.push(marker2.getLatLng());

//From documentation https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline
// create a red polyline from an arrays of LatLng points
var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs,
{
color: 'purple',
weight: 7,
opacity: 0.7,
dashArray: '20,15',
lineJoin: 'round'
}).addTo(map);

// zoom the map to the polyline
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
</script>

</body>
</html>

